# Grep filenames in a directory

Tags: bash, grep, filenames

I have the following line in bash where I get all files that contains 'result_finales' pattern.

```
files=("$dir"/*"result_finales"* )
```

That is correct, but I want also to get those files that contains .txt and .csv extesion.

I can't do it appending it to my array.

Like here:

```
files=("$dir"/*"result_finales"* "$dir"/*"*.txt"* )
```

Any idea?

Comment: files=("$dir"/*"result_finales"* "$dir"/*".txt" )

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` :

```
files=$(find "$dir" -name "*result_finales*" -o -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.csv")
```

Comment: This breaks if filenames contain spaces.